# Integrating MVC3 into an existing Classic ASP application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic

We have a very large application written in classic ASP.  The application consists of a single codebase which is accessed by multiple tenants, each of which has their own database.  The application has been developed over a number of years.

Initially we were going to write a new application in MVC3 which would take over from this application, and eventually migrate customers to this new application.

We are now wondering if it is viable to add to the existing application gradually using code written in MVC3.  At some point, we would expect the whole application to be running in MVC3 with no classic ASP left.  The application would have to act as a single application, with one login giving access to the existing classic asp parts of the system as well as the new parts written in MVC3.

Does anyone have experience of doing this?  What issues are we likely to face?  Are there any pitfalls we should look out for?

Comment: My advice to you would be not to do that. You would be much better served to start a new MVC3 project and start migrating areas/pieces as needed/scheduled.

You will have way too much "baggage" otherwise. Doing it this way will also help you clean up some of that old classic ASP code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in the process of completing a (painful and long) migration from a Classic ASP site to MVC3.
I looked at running both side-by-side in detail because this is a large ecommerce website I have migrated and it would have been beneficial.
The issues I came across and which eventually led me to abandon this option are as follows:

- If you have URL rewriting on your Classic ASP website then it is
  likely going to interfere with ASP.NET MVC routing

  Authentication is going to be very difficult because of the way
  authCookies are set in both technologies

In my case both of these points were show-stoppers.

Saying that, there have been some interesting developments in the open source arena since I started that try to tackle the issue of migrating Classic ASP sites to MVC. 
Specifically, you might want to take a look at the [ASP Classic Compiler on codeplex](http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/). It looks promising.